# Django command that opens a twisted socket client leaves idle database connections

Tags: python, django, postgresql, twisted

I'm using twisted to connect to a socket server and I am running twisted by using a django command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

from twisted.internet import reactor, task
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from django.conf import settings


class SocketClientProtocol(LineReceiver):

    MAX_LENGTH = 64*1024*1024

    def __init__(self):
        self.setLineMode()

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "CONNECTION ESTABLISHED"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "CONNECTION LOST"
        print reason.getErrorMessage()

    def lengthLimitExceeded(self, length):
        print "EXCEED"
        print length

    def lineReceived(self, msg):
        data = json.loads(msg)
        #do sth with the data from the socket server
        handle_message(data["type"], data["data"])


class SocketClientFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print 'Started to connect.'

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected'
        self.resetDelay()
        return SocketClientProtocol()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason)

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        client_factory = SocketClientFactory()
        reactor.connectUNIX(settings.UNIX_OUT_SOCKET, client_factory)
        reactor.run()
```

I'm starting this command via `python manage.py connect` and then let the process run next to an wsgi webserver behind Apache. This works quite nicely but I am having the problem that database connections, started within this socket client, will often not be closed correctly and just pile up as open and idle connections.

Output of `select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'lt';`:

```
 datid | datname |  pid  | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         | xact_start |          query_start          |         state_change          | waiting | state |            query                                                                                                                                        
 36649 | lt      | 11026 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55167 | 2016-05-31 15:50:38.417288+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:38.450209+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:38.451045+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 11132 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55348 | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.057967+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.089656+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.090441+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 10386 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       53816 | 2016-05-31 15:49:19.597695+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:49:19.633149+02 | 2016-05-31 15:49:19.634685+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 11145 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55356 | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.353581+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.389896+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:48.390985+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 11150 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55373 | 2016-05-31 15:50:49.705282+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:49.7269+02   | 2016-05-31 15:50:49.729029+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiodata"."id", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."index", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."source_file", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."duration", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."audiostream_id", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."start_timestamp", "mediatorapp_audiodata"."stop_timestamp" FROM "mediatorapp_audiodata" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiodata"."id" = 419871
 36649 | lt      | 10944 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       54990 | 2016-05-31 15:50:27.940832+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:27.978202+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:27.97917+02  | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 11059 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55243 | 2016-05-31 15:50:42.737117+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:42.773878+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:42.774562+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 11127 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       55342 | 2016-05-31 15:50:47.868249+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:47.905184+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:47.90642+02  | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
 36649 | lt      | 10901 |    16384 | dbuser  |                  | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       54896 | 2016-05-31 15:50:23.208558+02 |            | 2016-05-31 15:50:23.246194+02 | 2016-05-31 15:50:23.247041+02 | f       | idle  | SELECT "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."language_tag", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."session_id", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."out_file", "mediatorapp_audiostream"."source_file" FROM "mediatorapp_audiostream" WHERE "mediatorapp_audiostream"."id" = '1104880479774183399:de'
```

At some point, this leads to the following error:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

The queries that are listed above are generated by this function:

```
def get_audio_stream(audiostream_id):
    try:
        return AudioStream.objects.get(id=audiostream_id)
    except AudioStream.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

So I am simply trying to get an object by its id. As far as I know, Django should close the connection afterwards, but it doesn't. Is is not the only query that hangs from time to time, others are as well. But this one is the most frequent one.

I'm using the latest django (9.6), twisted 15.5 and Postgresql 9.3. I already tried setting CONN_MAX_AGE to different values but without success.

So what is cause of this problem? Is it because I'm running it behind this twisted engine? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no code that creates connection to postgres in the code you posted above. The problem lies elsewhere, maybe your server code which the code above connects to does not close the database connection when the client disconnects.

EDIT: If you are using Django ORM calls from within a non-WSGI application the database connections are not automatically closed. The automatic connection management is only done within the context of a WSGI request. It does this via the `signals.request_finished` signal.

You can manually manage connections and close them when they are not needed with the following code:

```
from django import db

# Use this to close all configured db connections after your query code.
# Note that Django ORM performs lazy queries, i.e. only executing SQL if
# you access the Model object properties retrieved from DB. So you should
# do this after you have finished ORM object tasks.
db.connections.close_all()

# or use this
db.connection.close()

# or for more control over which connection:
db.connections['default'].close()  # closes the default DB connection
```

If you are going to manage connections manually you will also want to manage transactions manually as well.

Comment: I updated my question. I just simply try to get an object from the database. Django is performing the lower lever database interaction and is, as far as I know, supposed to close the connection immediately. But it often doesn't.

Comment: Is that query code running from inside a Django view? Are you using Django as intended, that is as a WSGI application? i.e. running it using gunicorn or runserver.

Comment: I am running the query code from inside the django command, inside the function `handle_message()`.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. I hope it solves your problem. On a side note, if you don't really need the other features of Django besides the ORM you are probably better off using something like SQLAlchemy and then convert your management command to just a simple python script using argparse so that it can process command line arguments.

Comment: It took me a while to get it working. I found out that the main reason was not so much that I ran things inside this Django command but more that I at one point spawned a separate thread. And within that thread, the connections weren't always closed properly. However, your suggestion of closing the connection manually solved this problem. Thanks.